# Can you hide variations when a specific choice is not in stock

Tags: wordpress

Can you hide variations when a specific choice is not in stock in woocommerce
Once I have listed an item with variations, is there a way to automatically hide choices once they have sold out (out of stock)? TIA!

Comment: Can you show us an example of the code you have now?

Comment: yes see this site for demo http://www.skyverge.com/blog/add-sold-out-to-woocommerce-variable-product-dropdow/

Comment: Could I see your website?

Comment: sorry my website is under construction.it is not live now